# Error when load one page in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2012

I create web web app in visual studio and after build project , run the IIS 
and get preview via firfox.When go to once of pages get this error.

[image]

In this page exist an userControl that code behinde contain this :

```
  namespace Module_first
{
    public partial class TaskList : ModuleUserControlBase
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
          if (!IsPostBack)
    {
          var taskController=new TaskController();
            tasks_DataGrid.DataSource = taskController.GetTasks();
            tasks_DataGrid.DataBind(); 
    }
            btn_add_Task.NavigateUrl = ModuleContext.EditUrl("Edit");
        }

    }
}
```

and user control codes :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TaskList.ascx.cs" Inherits="Module_first.TaskList" %>


<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="tasks_DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    GridLines="None">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass=""></HeaderStyle>
    <ItemStyle CssClass=""></ItemStyle>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" HeaderText="Name" />
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Description" HeaderStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="Description" />
    </Columns>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundColumn DataField="IsComplete" HeaderStyle-Width="125px" HeaderText="IsComplete ?" />
    </Columns>

</asp:DataGrid>
<ul class="dnnAction dnnClear">
    <li>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="btn_add_Task" Text="Create New Task"></asp:HyperLink>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is somethis any unhandled code which occured in your app directly thrown to the IIS .if possible debug it or please post the code !!

Comment: I update question soon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Error is this line :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I change like this and solved

```
protected void On_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```